# Bootstrap svg link in background-image doesn't work for radio buttons, checkboxes, icons etc

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, svg, bootstrap-4

I wanted to customize standard Bootstrap with my own styles, so i copied html page with all Bootstrap elements from bootswatch.com/default. I've changed directories in "link" and "script" tags to directories in my project with required Bootstrap and other files.

It all worked, but when I scrolled page I found out that white circles inside radio buttons and check marks inside chechboxes are missing:

Should be: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NKeF.png).
What I got: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VNNa.png).

I thought that there are no required styles for that in my bootstrap. Then I went to code inspector to find a solution for the problem.

Circle (or other element) was added using background-image with svg image: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU7rO.png). On my page it was: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3jo4.png). In the link from bootswatch.com was a circle (or other element): [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja4C9.png). I got [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPWlW.png). I thought my Bootstrap has wrong style for this. But everything mathed with Bootstrap from bootswatch.com and all was ok with variable for background-image: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCZyc.png). I copied the link from bootswatch.com and overwritten the style in my bootstrap, but nothing changed: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngVPJ.png).

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Provide some code please. We can help but need code to debug and find the error

Comment: Yes, please provide your code, this is not a screenshot sharing service :) For clarification read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in YUICompressor (which compresses .css and .js files):

https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/304

Whitespaces required in the SVG string are deleted. This leads to the inefficiency of the CSS rule background-image.